# How to convert rome date format "Sun Jan 08 02:25:00 IST 2012" date to sql date

Tags: java, jsp, datetime, date, rome

I am using **rome 0.9** for getting **rss** feeds.but from that getting blog post's date
as in the format "Sun Jan 08 02:25:00 IST 2012" .

I am unable to **convert this date format to the sql date format**.Actually i want to sort the blog posts according to the post date.

How to parse the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this way,

```
String str_date  = "Sun Jan 08 02:25:00 IST 2012";
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    Date today = null;
    try {
        today = (Date)fmt.parse(str_date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

    java.sql.Date dt = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
    System.out.println(dt.toString());
```

Comment: Kushan,getting error like java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:138)
I am using code like this java.sql.Date postsqlDate =  java.sql.Date.valueOf(dt);
and dt is like this-Tue Jan 17 22:35:00 IST 2012

Comment: Kushan i am getting null in place of updated date from rome...So at the time of the insertion it fire exception as nullpointer exception.For this reason i added  today=fmt.parse("0000-00-00 00:00:00"); as a default date but it fires exception as  Unparseable date..What i should keep the default date.